# How Can I remove Seconds in Date and Time Format

Tags: javascript, react-native

I have a Date and Time, Format like  `2017-07-26 14:49:49` but I don't want Seconds. How can I remove the seconds?

I want only `2017-07-26 14:49` like this in react-native.js

Comment: `date.setSeconds(0)`. Note this will set it to `14:49:00`. If you are open to use a lib, use moment.js. Then you can do `moment().format(dd/MM/YYYY hh:mm)`

Comment: Did you consider using the Date object and formatting it yourself?

Comment: Do you have reservations using a standard library for that like [momentjs](https://momentjs.com/)?

Comment: 2017-07-26 14:49 I want Date format and  Hrr:mm

Comment: just now  i am giving this like below

Comment: var newDate = moment(completeItem._source.post_date).format(dd/MM/YYYY hh:mm);

Comment: but not Get it now

Comment: yes@Rowland I installed